# Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-batch

I have two tables\entities that are connected with a forging key.

```
 @Entity
 public class SwapEngineReport {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "FilePath")
  private String filePath;
  @Column(name = "FileName")
  private String fileName;
  @Column(name = "LastModifiedDate")
  private LocalDate lastModifiedDate;
  @Column(name = "LoadedDate")
  private LocalDate loadedDate;
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "SwapEngineReport2SwapEngineReportType", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = 
  "FK_SwapEngineReport_SwapEngineReportType"))
  private SwapEngineReportType swapEngineReportType;

  public SwapEngineReportType getSwapEngineReportType() {
    return swapEngineReportType;
  }
  public void setSwapEngineReportType(SwapEngineReportType swapEngineReportType) {
    this.swapEngineReportType = swapEngineReportType;
  }

  @Entity
  public class SwapEngineReportType {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "Type")
  private String type;
  @Column(name = "Description")
  private String description;
```

During the process stage, I am initiating the SEReport object and setting all the necessary values including the Type object.

```
    @Override
    public SwapEngineReport process(Resource resource) throws Exception {
     SwapEngineReport swapEngineReport = new SwapEngineReport();
     ......
     SwapEngineReportType type = new SwapEngineReportType();
     if(inputReourceValue.equals("dailyex")){type.setType("DAILY_EX");}
     if(inputReourceValue.equals("status")) {type.setType("STATUS");}
     swapEngineReport.setSwapEngineReportType(type);
    
     return swapEngineReport;
```

What I don’t understand is why the write method is not working.
This is the error message:

> Bean property 'swapEngineReport2swapEngineReportType' is not readable
> or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter
> match the parameter type of the setter?

```
 return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<SwapEngineReport>().beanMapped().dataSource(dataSource)
            .sql(environment.getProperty("insertToSwapEngineReport")).build();
```

And SQL:

```
  INSERT INTO SwapEngineReport 
  (filePath,fileName,lastModifiedDate,swapEngineReport2swapEngineReportType) VALUES 
   (:filePath,:fileName,:lastModifiedDate,:swapEngineReport2swapEngineReportType)
```

Can anyone, please assist me to understand what I am missing.

Thank you

Comment: swapEngineReport2swapEngineReportType is of SwapEngineReportType type.

What is the column type in the SwapEngineReport table ?

Comment: the column type is varchar

Comment: You can't have a complex object on one side and a varchar on the other ? What would you like to store in the varchar ? The type ? The description ? Both ? Hibernate can't know that

Comment: I would like to insert the Type since there is @ManyToOne relationship. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: your :swapEngineReport2swapEngineReportType variable should contain swapEngineReportType.getType (you will need to create an appropriated getter in the class.